# Concurrent file access in Python

Tags: python, windows, file, concurrency

I have a Python script, which appends content to a large file a few times a second. I also need a second process, which occasionally opens that large file, and reads from it.

How do I do that in Windows? In C++ I could simply open a file with _SH_DENYNO, but what is the equivalent in Python?

Comment: It seems like you're using the file as an IPC mechanism.  It might be worth rethinking that if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in 'r+b' mode. You would then have a single file object which could be accessed by the two different processes.

Doing so requires some communication between processes (or careful handling of the processes) to about the current state of the file.

Overall, this seems a better approach then over-riding OS / file system locking to create duplicate file objects, which seems like the sort of thing that can't possibly end well.

You could also simply have the writer process open/close the file every time it accesses it, then the same with the reader process, assuming this is feasible for your program.